# Determining number of possible addresses in a subnet / which subnet an address belongs to?

Tags: networking, ip-address, bitmask, subnet

Suppose we have a class B network with subnet mask `255.255.240.0`. How can we check what is the maximum number of hosts in this subnet? And how we can determine to which subnet host with IP address `130.50.31.6` belongs?

Answer (score 3):

Subnet masks are just some number of binary `1`s to denote "this space is not available". For example, take the subnet mask:

```
255.255.240.0
```

This is actually made up of four bytes, which are separated visually by dots (what is called a "dotted quad"). So, in binary, that would be:

```
11111111 11111111 11110000 00000000
```

A "mask" defining that the first 20 bits of the address are accounted for, leaving you with 12 addressable bits. So your address space is:

```
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 -
00000000 00000000 00001111 11111111
```

... plus whatever your base address is. ie, in this case, 4096 unique addresses (converting from the binary `00001111 11111111`)

The base address is a number whose `1` bits are contained entirely within the "mask" portion of a given IP address. That is the meaning of the "mask" part of the subnet mask: Any address within the subnet mask, binary AND'ed with the subnet mask, will give you the base address of the subnet.

So, let's take a look of the address and the mask which we have in this example:

```
            |   dotted quad    |             binary
------------+------------------+------------------------------------
    Address | 130. 50. 31.  6  | 10000010 00110010 00011111 00000110
Subnet Mask | 255.255.240.  0  | 11111111 11111111 11110000 00000000
```

Using the rule above, we can then find the base address:

```
   10000010 00110010 00011111 00000110
 & 11111111 11111111 11110000 00000000
---------------------------------------
   10000010 00110010 00010000 00000000
```

or, as a dotted quad, `130.50.16.0`.

As a shorthand form of describing a subnet, rather than specifying "base address" and "subnet mask", it is often written as `<base address>`/`<number of 1 bits in the mask>`. So, the full description of the subnet which `130.50.31.6` is on, given the subnet mask of `255.255.240.0`, is `130.50.16.0/20`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this calculator to get all information:

http://www.subnet-calculator.com/subnet.php?net_class=B